# Do potions have an effect on your companion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, do potions like Resist Fire have any effects on your followers?  If I drink a Resist Fire potion, does that also increase the fire resistance of my followers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Imbibing a potion or casting a beneficial spell on yourself has no property of transitivity to your follower. (Follower is the official term, if only because "Companion" is used to refer to... well, one of the [Companions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Companions))

I'm not sure under what situations NPCs drink potions in their inventory, but it does happen (or at least is 'faked' from time to time).

Comment: Thanks Raven.  That's kind of what I thought.  My "follower" seems to easily get "burned" by my fire spells.

Comment: If you give them healing potions they'll drink them in battle.